# Oracle SQl Dev, how to calc num of weekdays between 2 dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count

Does anyone know how  can I calculate the number of weekdays between two date fields? I'm using oracle sql developer. I need to find the average of weekdays between multiple start and end dates. So I need to get the count of days for each record so I can average them out. Is this something that can be done as one line in the `SELECT` part of my query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is similar to Nicholas's, which isn't a surprise because you need a subquery with a `CONNECT BY` to spin out a list of dates. The dates can then be counted while checking for the day of the week. The difference here is that it shows how to get the weekday count value on each line of the results:

```
SELECT
  FromDate,
  ThruDate,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM DUAL
     WHERE TO_CHAR(FromDate + LEVEL - 1, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ThruDate - FromDate + 1
  ) AS Weekday_Count
FROM myTable
```

The count is inclusive, meaning it includes `FromDate` and `ThruDate`. This query assumes that your dates don't have a time component; if they do you'll need to `TRUNC` the date columns in the subquery.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it the following way :

Lets say we want to know how many weekdays between `start_date='01.08.2013'` and `end_date='04.08.2013'` In this example `start_date` and `end_date` are string literals. If your `start_date` and `end_date` are of `date` datatype, the  `TO_DATE()` function won't be needed:

```
select count(*) as num_of_weekdays
  from ( select level as dnum
           from dual
        connect by (to_date(end_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - 
                    to_date(start_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1) - level >= 0) s
where to_char(sysdate + dnum, 'DY', 
              'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') not in ('SUN', 'SAT')
```

Result:

```
num_of_weekdays
--------------
2
```

Comment: I read Oracle documentation about hierarchical queries but I still don't understand how level helps here. Can you please explain how this part works?
 `connect by (to_date(end_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - 
                    to_date(start_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1) - level >= 0)`

Comment: is ok, but I think is necessary to change sysdate to start_date to get right results.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout my complete working function code and explanation at
https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/oracle-calculating-business-days-between-two-dates-in-oracle/

Once you have created the function just use the function as part of the SELECT statement and pass in the two date columns for Start and End dates like this:

SELECT Begin_Date, End_Date, fn_GetBusinessDaysInterval(Begin_Date, End_Date) AS BusinessDays FROM YOURTABLE;