# Work days in 21-20 period

Tags: sql, oracle

First, I'm sorry for my English because it is not my first language, but I try.

In the last days I find a query to calculate work days (query 1), but I have a problem to calculate when the period is 21-20. I created a case to calculate automatically the first and last day on the period (21-20) and works fine.

--Query 1

```
SELECT  SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR((SYSDATE-ROWNUM),'DY'),'SUN',0,'SAT',0,1)) 
FROM    all_objects
WHERE   ROWNUM <= LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) - SYSDATE
```

--Query 2

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '21/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM/YYYY')
        ELSE '21/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
    END FIRST_DAY
    , CASE
         WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '20/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
         ELSE '20/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, +1), 'MM/YYYY')
    END LAST_DAY
FROM DUAL
```

Now, the big problem is how to put query 2 inside query 1? I try a few times and did not work!
Feel free to make any changes in my code.
And again, sorry for my English poor.
Thanks!

**Edit**

Query 2 inside query 1 ok! Now the problem is the result because this return 21 and not 22. I’m not put +1 in this query hehehe

--Query 2 inside query 1

```
SELECT  SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(CASE
                                     WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '20/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
                                     ELSE '20/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, +1), 'MM/YYYY')
                                END)-ROWNUM),'DY'),'SUN',0,'SAT',0,1))
FROM    all_objects
WHERE   ROWNUM <= TO_DATE(CASE
                         WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '20/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
                         ELSE '20/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, +1), 'MM/YYYY')
                      END) 
                     - TO_DATE(CASE
                                  WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '21/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM/YYYY')
                                  ELSE '21/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
                               END)
```

--Result: 21

**Edit**

In the database there is a table of working days. I can use this to calculate, but I don’t know how to do it using a period like 21-20 (Ex. Between 21/11/2016 and 20/12/2016).

```
select  * 
from    pcdiasuteis 
where   pcdiasuteis.data >= '01/01/2017’
```

--Result

```
Row #   CODFILIAL   DATA        DIAFINANCEIRO   DIAVENDAS
1       1           01/01/2017  N               N        
2       1           02/01/2017  S               S        
3       1           03/01/2017  S               S        
4       1           04/01/2017  S               S        
5       1           05/01/2017  S               S        
6       1           06/01/2017  S               S        
7       1           07/01/2017  N               N        
8       1           08/01/2017  N               N
```

--DIAFINANCEIRO is the financial calendar and DIAVENDAS is the sales calendar.

**Edit**

OMG, I’m so stupid! It was much simple than I thought it would be.

--Query

```
SELECT  COUNT(PCDIASUTEIS.DATA) DIAS_TRABALHO
FROM    PCDIASUTEIS 
WHERE   PCDIASUTEIS.DIAVENDAS = 'S'
    AND PCDIASUTEIS.CODFILIAL = 1
    AND PCDIASUTEIS.DATA BETWEEN (CASE
                                     WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '21/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM/YYYY')
                                     ELSE '21/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
                                  END) AND (CASE
                                               WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') <= '20' THEN '20/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
                                               ELSE '20/'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, +1), 'MM/YYYY')
                                            END)
```

However the question remains because I don't want to use a WorkDay table in another cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQl Dev, how to calc num of weekdays between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534404/oracle-sql-dev-how-to-calc-num-of-weekdays-between-2-dates)

Comment: There can often be a benefit from using a calendar table http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/ (This is  a tsql link but the principal is the same)

Comment: So, another problem... I can't create any object in DB. For this I need to open a solicitation to the DBA and he can deny it as he has done before. This would not be a good solution for this case.
Sorry but I forgot to quote that in question.
Thanks!

Comment: How do you handle public holiday like 1st of January?

Comment: At this point I don’t need to deal with it, but it can be a problem in the future. I took a look now and found in the database a table with working days. I'll edit the question adding this information.